# I am trying to store the hashed password in password reset flow. It is giving me Internal Server Error in ADB2C Azure custom policy for password reset

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework, azure-identity

I am using azure adb2c custom policies , my requirement is to block the user from using the last 10 password. So i am trying to store the password using password reset custom policies . I took the reference from [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-history).
I am getting internal server error .

Exception Message:An internal error has occurred., CorrelationID:ce643089-eec8-496f-96b6-275fa705c0dd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="XXX.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_HISTORYResetPassword" DeploymentMode="Development" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights" PublicPolicyUri="http://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_HISTORYResetPassword">
   <BasePolicy>
      <TenantId>XXX.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
      <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
   </BasePolicy>
   <BuildingBlocks>
      <ClaimsSchema>
         <ClaimType Id="IsPasswordValid">
            <DisplayName>password is valid</DisplayName>
            <DataType>boolean</DataType>
            <UserHelpText>password is not one of past 5 passwords</UserHelpText>
         </ClaimType>
         <ClaimType Id="userPassHash">
            <DisplayName>request JSON body for user password hash info</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
            <UserHelpText>request JSON body for user password hash info</UserHelpText>
         </ClaimType>
         <ClaimType Id="hashedPassword">
            <DisplayName>Hashed password</DisplayName>
            <DataType>string</DataType>
         </ClaimType>
      </ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimsTransformations>
         <ClaimsTransformation Id="HashPasswordWithEmail" TransformationMethod="Hash">
            <InputClaims>
               <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" TransformationClaimType="plaintext" />
               <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="salt" />
            </InputClaims>
            <InputParameters>
               <InputParameter Id="randomizerSecret" DataType="string" Value="B2C_1A_AccountTransformSecret" />
            </InputParameters>
            <OutputClaims>
               <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedPassword" TransformationClaimType="hash" />
            </OutputClaims>
         </ClaimsTransformation>
         <ClaimsTransformation Id="GeneratePassHashBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
            <InputClaims>
               <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectid" TransformationClaimType="username" />
               <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedPassword" TransformationClaimType="hash" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
               <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPassHash" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
            </OutputClaims>
         </ClaimsTransformation>
      </ClaimsTransformations>
   </BuildingBlocks>
   <ClaimsProviders>
      <ClaimsProvider>
         <DisplayName>Password reset overrides</DisplayName>
         <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
               <Metadata>
                  <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">false</Item>
               </Metadata>
            </TechnicalProfile>
         </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
      <ClaimsProvider>
         <DisplayName>Technical Profiles For Checking Password History</DisplayName>
         <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="ValidatePasswordHash">
               <DisplayName>Validate that new password is not one of past 5 passwords</DisplayName>
               <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
               <Metadata>
                  <!--Sample: update the ServiceUrl with the Url to your password hash service, e.g. passhash.azurewebsites.net -->
                  <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/api/ValidatePasswordHash?code=9AWILE36B_BAJJtRrnX0ASyHMIbyK_ZFgoxiUR1OCBxyAzFugayEsA==</Item>
                  <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
                  <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
                  <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
                  <Item Key="UserMessageIfDnsResolutionFailed">UserMessageIfRequestTimeout121212</Item>
                  <Item Key="UserMessageIfRequestTimeout">teset1</Item>
                  <Item Key="UserMessageIfCircuitOpen">true</Item>
                  <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">userPassHash</Item>
                  <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Cannot process your request right now, please try again later.</Item>
               </Metadata>
               <!-- <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MyClientId" />
                    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MyClientSecret" />
                  </CryptographicKeys> -->
               <InputClaimsTransformations>
                  <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="HashPasswordWithEmail" />
                  <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GeneratePassHashBody" />
               </InputClaimsTransformations>
               <InputClaims>
                  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPassHash" />
               </InputClaims>
            </TechnicalProfile>
         </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
      <ClaimsProvider>
         <DisplayName>AAD Overrides</DisplayName>
         <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId-ForHistory">
               <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
               <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
               <Metadata>
                  <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
               </Metadata>
               <CryptographicKeys>
                  <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
               </CryptographicKeys>
               <InputClaims>
                  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
               </InputClaims>
               <OutputClaims>
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IsPasswordValid" DefaultValue="true" />
               </OutputClaims>
               <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ValidatePasswordHash" />
                  <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
               </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            </TechnicalProfile>
         </TechnicalProfiles>
      </ClaimsProvider>
   </ClaimsProviders>
   <UserJourneys>
      <UserJourney Id="PasswordResetWithHistoryCheck">
         <OrchestrationSteps>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
               <ClaimsExchanges>
                  <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
               </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
               <ClaimsExchanges>
                  <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId-ForHistory" />
               </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
            <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
         </OrchestrationSteps>
         <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
      </UserJourney>
   </UserJourneys>
   <RelyingParty>
      <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="PasswordResetWithHistoryCheck" />
      <UserJourneyBehaviors>
         <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="94701752-973e-4316-afd7-9f2fdb96c028" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
         <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
      </UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
         <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
         <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
         <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IsPasswordValid" />
         </OutputClaims>
         <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
   </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: What do the logs say when you set up Application Insights?

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/438 -solution